How to build ball bearings based on Modelica language?
How to build a ball bearing?
It is necessary to conduct modeling simulation and visual analysis of its failure-free and failure dynamic models.
Currently, I use the bodyshape component to visualize the bearing by calling solidworks drawings. However, some problems were encountered when specifically building the bearings. For example, the addition of balls and retainers in bearings. Constraints and motion cannot be added. The number of equations and unknowns will be unequal, leading to model errors.
I use the component bodyshape to read SolidWorks drawings. The current setup is as follows: the outer ring of the bearing is fixed and a component fixed is connected. A component revolute1 is connected between the bearing outer ring and ball 1. A component revolute2 is connected between ball 1 and the inner ring of the bearing. Among them, the component bearingFriction is added to the component revolute2 (I understand that this can add friction). Add a moment and realExpression[3] at the other end of the bearing bore. This enables the first ball to roll. But now I haven't been able to add a second ball. There are always situations where the equation and the unknown are not equal.

model Main
  annotation (Diagram(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-250, 410}, {660, 730}}, 
    grid = {2, 2})), Icon(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, preserveAspectRatio = false, initialScale = 0.1, grid = {2, 2}), graphics = {Rectangle(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}), Text(extent = {{-120, 100}, {120, 140}}, textString = "Main"), Bitmap(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, fileName = ".\\bearing.jpg")}));
  inner Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.World world(
    animateWorld = false, 
    animateGravity = false) 
    annotation (Placement(transformation(origin = {-220, 561.7547938270272}, 
      extent = {{-10, -10}, {10.000000000000028, 10}})));

  model Tybodyshape_ball_1
    extends Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyShape;
    annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = false, extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, grid = {1, 1}), graphics = {Bitmap(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, fileName = "ball_1_prt.jpg")}));
  end Tybodyshape_ball_1;
  Tybodyshape_ball_1 ball_1(
    animation = true, 
    animateSphere = false, 
    r = {0, 0, 0}, 
    r_CM = {0, 0, 0}, 
    m = 0.00205743, 
    I_11 = 1.2971e-008, 
    I_22 = 1.29706e-008, 
    I_33 = 1.29706e-008, 
    I_21 = -4.53357e-032, 
    I_31 = 3.70194e-016, 
    I_32 = -6.19219e-041, 
    shapeType = "5.stl", 
    r_shape = {0, 0, 0}, 
    lengthDirection = {1, 0, 0}, 
    widthDirection = {0, 1, 0}, 
    length = 1, 
    width = 1, 
    height = 1, 
    extra = 1, 
    color = {198, 193, 188}, 
    specularCoefficient = 0.7, 
    r_0(start = {-2.03501e-018, -0.0168136, 0.000220603}, fixed = false)) 
    annotation (Placement(transformation(origin = {98, 654}, 
      extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  model Tybodyshape_ball_1_2
    extends Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyShape;
    annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = false, extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, grid = {1, 1}), graphics = {Bitmap(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, fileName = "ball_1_prt.jpg")}));
  end Tybodyshape_ball_1_2;

  model Tybodyshape_cage_new
    extends Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyShape;
    annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = false, extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, grid = {1, 1}), graphics = {Bitmap(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, fileName = "cage_new_prt.jpg")}));
  end Tybodyshape_cage_new;
  model Tybodyshape_inner_race_1
    extends Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyShape;
    annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = false, extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, grid = {1, 1}), graphics = {Bitmap(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, fileName = "inner_race_1_prt.jpg")}));
  end Tybodyshape_inner_race_1;
  Tybodyshape_inner_race_1 inner_race_1(
    animation = true, 
    animateSphere = false, 
    r = {0, 0, 0}, 
    r_CM = {0, 0, 0}, 
    m = 0.0301719, 
    I_11 = 4.36027e-006, 
    I_22 = 2.71662e-006, 
    I_33 = 2.71662e-006, 
    I_21 = -3.36432e-015, 
    I_31 = -1.45451e-022, 
    I_32 = -1.93935e-022, 
    shapeType = "6.stl", 
    r_shape = {0, 21, 0}, 
    lengthDirection = {1, 1.16033e-028, 4.37135e-029}, 
    widthDirection = {-1.14809e-028, 0.733312, 0.679892}, 
    length = 1, 
    width = 1, 
    height = 1, 
    extra = 1, 
    color = {198, 193, 188}, 
    specularCoefficient = 0.7, 
    r_0(start = {0, 0, 0}, fixed = false)) 
    annotation (Placement(transformation(origin = {458, 654}, 
      extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  model Tybodyshape_out_race_1
    extends Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyShape;
    annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = false, extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, grid = {1, 1}), graphics = {Bitmap(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}}, fileName = "out_race_1_prt.jpg")}));
  end Tybodyshape_out_race_1;
  Tybodyshape_out_race_1 out_race_1(
    animation = true, 
    animateSphere = false, 
    r = {0, 0, 0}, 
    r_CM = {0, 0, 0}, 
    m = 0.0553286, 
    I_11 = 2.64058e-005, 
    I_22 = 1.41716e-005, 
    I_33 = 1.41716e-005, 
    I_21 = 3.53996e-013, 
    I_31 = 3.8787e-022, 
    I_32 = 1.55148e-021, 
    shapeType = "7.stl", 
    r_shape = {0, -21, 0}, 
    lengthDirection = {1, 0, 0}, 
    widthDirection = {0, 1, 0}, 
    length = 1, 
    width = 1, 
    height = 1, 
    extra = 1, 
    color = {198, 193, 188}, 
    specularCoefficient = 0.7, 
    r_0(start = {0, 0, 0}, fixed = false)) 
    annotation (Placement(transformation(origin = {-96, 561.7547938270272}, 
      extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));

  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.Fixed fixed1(animation = false) 
    annotation (Placement(transformation(origin = {-158, 561.7547938270272}, 
      extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})), __MWORKS(BlockSystem(StateMachine)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Joints.Revolute revolute(useAxisFlange = true, animation = false, n = {1, 0, 0}) 
    annotation (Placement(transformation(origin = {342, 654}, 
      extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Joints.Revolute revolute1(useAxisFlange = false, animation = false, n = {1, 0, 0}) 
    annotation (Placement(transformation(origin = {-50, 561.7547938270272}, 
      extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})), __MWORKS(BlockSystem(StateMachine)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression realExpression[3](y = 0.001) annotation (Placement(transformation(origin = {574, 654}, 
    extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}})), __MWORKS(BlockSystem(StateMachine)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Forces.WorldTorque torque(animation = false) 
    annotation (Placement(transformation(origin = {526, 654}, 
      extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}})), __MWORKS(BlockSystem(StateMachine)));

  Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Components.BearingFriction bearingFriction1(useSupport = false, peak = 1, tau_pos = [0, 1]) 
    annotation (Placement(transformation(origin = {352, 694}, 
      extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})), __MWORKS(BlockSystem(StateMachine)));
equation
  connect(fixed1.frame_b, out_race_1.frame_a) 
    annotation (Line(origin = {-107, 562}, 
      points = {{-41, -0.24520617297275749}, {1.0000000000000142, -0.24520617297275749}}, 
      color = {95, 95, 95}, 
      thickness = 0.5));
  connect(revolute1.frame_a, out_race_1.frame_b) 
    annotation (Line(origin = {-60, 622}, 
      points = {{0, -60.24520617297276}, {-26, -60.24520617297276}}, 
      color = {95, 95, 95}, 
      thickness = 0.5));
  connect(realExpression.y, torque.torque) 
    annotation (Line(origin = {546, 654.3850644181664}, 
      points = {{17, -0.3850644181663938}, {-8, -0.3850644181663938}}, 
      color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(inner_race_1.frame_b, torque.frame_b) 
    annotation (Line(origin = {489, 597}, 
      points = {{-21, 57}, {27, 57}}, 
      color = {95, 95, 95}, 
      thickness = 0.5));
  connect(revolute.frame_b, inner_race_1.frame_a) 
    annotation (Line(origin = {399, 612}, 
      points = {{-47, 42}, {49, 42}}, 
      color = {95, 95, 95}, 
      thickness = 0.5));
  connect(revolute1.frame_b, ball_1.frame_a) 
    annotation (Line(origin = {18, 608}, 
      points = {{-58, -46.24520617297276}, {-28, -46.24520617297276}, {-28, 46}, {70, 46}}, 
      color = {95, 95, 95}, 
      thickness = 0.5));
  connect(bearingFriction1.flange_a, revolute.support) 
    annotation (Line(origin = {339, 679}, 
      points = {{3, 15}, {-11, 15}, {-11, -15}, {-3, -15}}, 
      color = {0, 0, 0}));
  connect(bearingFriction1.flange_b, revolute.axis) 
    annotation (Line(origin = {352, 679}, 
      points = {{10, 15}, {20, 15}, {20, -15}, {-10, -15}}, 
      color = {0, 0, 0}));
  connect(ball_1.frame_b, revolute.frame_a) 
    annotation (Line(origin = {214, 654}, 
      points = {{-106, 0}, {118, 0}}, 
      color = {95, 95, 95}, 
      thickness = 0.5));
end Main;



Sorry, this question is too general to give a good answer. Please provide details what you tried and what exactly your error is. If possible, add a minimal reproducible example and include the exact error messages you have. See the help page for details, like https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Thanks for your reply and suggestions. This is my first time using this website. Sorry there is a problem with the format of the question. Sorry for causing trouble to you. I'll try to be as detailed and compliant as possible. I have now made changes to the problem description.

The textual description of the model is hard to understand, could you post the code or at least a screenshot? Is it just about visualization or do you have equations describing the behavior of the bearing as well?

I have added the code. Currently, there are only two balls in this code (the bearing has 9 balls). Since the dynamic behavior analysis of the bearing (whether it is faulty or not) has been done, my idea is to first build the model of the ball bearing (considering only the bearing itself and its visualization). Then add this model to the existing model. Then realize the modeling simulation and visualization analysis of the bearing. If there is any problem with my idea, please give me some suggestions. Thank you very much.
